# How to compile simple C file using GNU C Compiler/gcc & Mobile-Terminal on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, c, gcc, compiler-construction, gnu

How to compile simple C file using GNU C Compiler/gcc & Mobile-Terminal on the iPhone?!
Do I need extra files?

Comment: iPhones don't come with compilers installed on them, let alone a full blown GCC installation. If you want to develop for an iPhone, you should use the official SDK.

Comment: You're best bet would be to use an SSH client for the iPhone and connect to some shell account you have on the Internet.

Comment: Did you already jailbreak your iphone? Only then can use use a GNU c compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice iphone os c/c++ compiler by (pH - Pedro Henrique).
look at http://www.spaziocellulare.com/ispazio/2009/03/29/iphone-os-cc-compiler-cydia/
or search cydia for the package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need setup extra packages from Cydia:

- Make
- iPhone 1.1.1 headers

The second one is no more available from Cydia, but there is header file from iPhone SDK must insert manually.

I'm not sure but I think it must unzip in ~/var/include (search about it!).

Answer (score -1):

You must insert header files in `/private/var/include`.